# Toggle button on navbar doesn't work - Twitter Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 and the button on the right side on the navbar doesn't work when I click on it.

Here's my Code:

```
<!-- HEADER -->        
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target=".bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">                    
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/LynxusLogo.png" /></a>
        </div>            

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                        
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" onmouseover="hoverHome(this);" onmouseout="unhoverHome(this);"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/About.png" onmouseover="hoverAbout(this);" onmouseout="unhoverAbout(this);"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Team.png" onmouseover="hoverTeam(this);" onmouseout="unhoverTeam(this);"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://lynxusapp.blogspot.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/Blog.png" onmouseover="hoverBlog(this);" onmouseout="unhoverBlog(this);"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Contact.png" onmouseover="hoverContact(this);" onmouseout="unhoverContact(this);"/></a></li>
            </ul>                    
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `data-target` on the button to use the id (`#`) instead of the class(`.`) selector

```
data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m97Vj/)

Comment: @duhzecca, does it work in the demo I provided?  If so, there's something else going on in your code.  Make sure you have links to jQuery.js and Bootstrap.js (and in that order).

Comment: Even in the demo is not working. I tested right now and it didn't work

Comment: On my code I deleted everything else and I just left the navbar inside of the body but it is still not working and I don't know why

Comment: The demo should be working.  The only reason it's sometimes iffy is because jsFiddle adds a `result` indicator that sits in the top right of the results pane and often occludes the Bootstrap toggle button.  You have to click on the bottom of the button.  Alternatively, view the [full page result of the demo by adding `/show` to the url](http://jsfiddle.net/m97Vj/show/)

Comment: We have no way to debug what's happening on your local machine.  Create a stripped down version and add it to jsFiddle.  If it's still broken there, then we can help.

Comment: I have the website online on the link: http://lynxusapp.com/

could you please take a look. I really appreciate it

Comment: @duhzecca, my first comment was to make sure jquery is added to your site.  Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>` and it will allow bootstrap.js to work. In the future, [you should open up your console to see if you have any errors](http://i.imgur.com/b2k9Tlr.png)

Comment: @duhzecca, BTW, using images for each one of your navbar elements is really inefficient.  You can get the same look with just a [small amount of CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/m97Vj/1/)